# How to find duplicate elements in array in effective way? I mean to say with very less iterations

Tags: java, arrays, count, duplicates

How to find the duplicate element in an array which is having lacks of elements? If I iterate the array for lacks of times the performance will became slow. What is the best way to iterate an array in efficient way? Or else can we use any other Java collection object to find the duplicates with less number of iterations or less time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashSet` because Sets don't allow duplicates, just loop over array of elements and insert them into a `HashSet` using the `add()` method. If the `add()` method returns back `false` then that element already exists in the set and it is there for your duplicate. This way you only loop over the array once which results in a time and space complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But suppose if we have 10Lakh elements in an array, again we have to iterate the 10lakh times. I don't want do do this. That's why im asking better than this approach to reduce the time complexity

Comment: I don't believe you can find duplicates in less than O(n).

Comment: I agree with @tgdavies. Other alternative solution result in time complexity of O(n^2) which is also not what you want

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the task conditions, the first approach is faster, and the last one is slower:

```java
Character[] chars = {'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'};
```

1. If you want to [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) certain elements and get [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) of them:

   ```java
   Long countB = Arrays.stream(chars)
           .filter(ch -> ch.equals('B')).count();

   System.out.println(countB); // 3
   ```
2. If you want to get an array of [`distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) elements:

   ```java
   Character[] distinct = Arrays.stream(chars)
           .distinct().toArray(Character[]::new);

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(distinct)); // [A, B, C]
   ```

   Or you can use [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

   ```java
   HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(chars));

   System.out.println(set); // [A, B, C]
   ```
3. If you want to [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) a map of duplicates:

   ```java
   Map<Character, Long> duplicates = Arrays.stream(chars)
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> ch, Collectors.counting()));

   System.out.println(duplicates); // {A=2, B=3, C=1}
   ```