# Extract less than 1% percentage values from a list

Tags: java, string, list, lambda, java-8

I have a list of `DataModel` pojo class. `percentage` field is in `String` format:

```java
public class DataModel implements Serializable {
    private String percentage;

    public String getPercentage() {
        return this.percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

A data sample:

```java
List<DataModel> list = new ArrayList();
DataModel d1 = new DataModel();
d1.setPercentage("20.34%");
DataModel d2 = new DataModel();
d2.setPercentage("30.04%");
DataModel d3 = new DataModel();
d3.setPercentage("10.34%");
DataModel d4 = new DataModel();
d4.setPercentage("0.34%");
list.add(d1);
list.add(d2);
list.add(d3);
list.add(d4);
```

I am able to sort the list in reverse order as below:

```java
list = list.sort(comparing(r ->
        Double.parseDouble(
                r.getPercentage().substring(0, r.getPercentage().length() - 1)),
        Comparator.reverseOrder()));

List<DataModel> fullList = new ArrayList();
List<DataModel> lessList = new ArrayList();
```

I need to fill the above list as below:

```
fullList ---> percentage > 1 (20.04%,20.34%,10.34%)
lessList ---> percentage < 1 (0.34%)
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
Map<Boolean, List<DataModel>> results = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                p -> p.getPercentage().startsWith("0.")));

List<DataModel> fullList = results.get(false);
List<DataModel> lessList = results.get(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to transform the *percentage* field to a `double` to make it easier to compare them and add a `toString` method to keep the view the same. Then you can easily access and represent the required data:

```java
public class DataModel implements Serializable {
    private double percentage;

    public DataModel(double percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

    public double getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return percentage + "%";
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<DataModel> list = List.of(
            new DataModel(20.34),
            new DataModel(30.04),
            new DataModel(10.34),
            new DataModel(0.34));

    System.out.println(list); // [20.34%, 30.04%, 10.34%, 0.34%]

    List<DataModel> fullList = list.stream()
            .filter(dm -> dm.getPercentage() > 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(fullList); // [20.34%, 30.04%, 10.34%]

    List<DataModel> lessList = list.stream()
            .filter(dm -> dm.getPercentage() < 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(lessList); // [0.34%]
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to find duplicate elements in array in effective way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344781/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use that percentage as double not string so u can compare it easily.
You can also create a comparator class for that object. You could do it like this:

```java
public class DataModelComparator implements Comparator<DataModel> {
    @Override
    public int compare(DataModel m1, DataModel m2) {
        return m1.getPercentage().compareTo(m2.getPercentage());
    }
}
```

So here you will be able to compare this objects by there percentage.
You can use this comparator like this:

```java
ArrayList<DataModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
DataModel d1 = new DataModel(2.56);
DataModel d2 = new DataModel(45.5);
models.add(d1, d2);
// now you have two objects created
// so if you want to sort them by their
// percentages you can do it like this:
Collections.sort(models, new DataModelComparator());
```

Internally the comparator class will send a 0 if the objects are equal, a -1 if the object is smaller than or a 1 if the object is bigger than.

After this your list will be ordered by it percentage and u can get the data how you need to with some if statement or so.