# How to remove duplicate String arrays in an ArrayList while disregarding the first index in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures

Say I have an `ArrayList<String[]>` like so:

```java
ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new String[]{"1", "hello", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"2", "car", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"3", "jack", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"4", "mcdonalds", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"5", "hello", "goodbye"});
```

```
[[1, hello, goodbye], [2, car, goodbye], [3, jack, goodbye],
 [4, mcdonalds, goodbye], [5, hello, goodbye]]
```

How can I write a function to remove duplicate String arrays in the ArrayList, while not taking into account the first index? "Duplicates" in this case would be: the first and last elements

```
[1, hello, goodbye], [5, hello, goodbye]
```

The resulting arrayList would be:

```
[[1, hello, goodbye], [2, car, goodbye], [3, jack, goodbye],
 [4, mcdonalds, goodbye]]
```

I can think of a very convoluted way which involves cloning the entire list to a temp variable, then setting all values in the original list to "dummy". From there the first index is standardized and you can compare between arrays. Then you can line up the indices of the duplicates and remove them from the original. That seems very inefficient and would be bad on big data sets however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number of `strings` is not predefined, and the order matters, you can use a `Set<List<String>>` as follows:

Iterate over the `ArrayList` elements and get a `List<String>` representing its strings (without the first one), if it's not in the set, add it, and add the array at the iteration to the resulting list:

```
List<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new String[]{"1", "hello", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"2", "car", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"3", "jack", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"4", "mcdonalds", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"5", "hello", "goodbye"});
        
Set<List<String>> set = new HashSet<>();
List<String[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
for(String[] arr : arrayList) {
     List<String> current = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length));
     if(!set.contains(current)) {
          res.add(arr);
          set.add(current);
     }
}
        
for(String[] arr : res)
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[1, hello, goodbye]
[2, car, goodbye]
[3, jack, goodbye]
[4, mcdonalds, goodbye]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well,you can just add them to the set and let the set do the work.

```
List<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new String[] { "1", "hello", "goodbye" });
arrayList.add(new String[] { "2", "car", "goodbye" });
arrayList.add(new String[] { "3", "jack", "goodbye" });
arrayList.add(new String[] { "4", "mcdonalds", "goodbye" });
arrayList.add(new String[] { "5", "hello", "goodbye" });

Comparator<String[]> comp =
        Comparator.comparing((String[] arr) -> arr[1])
                .thenComparing(arr -> arr[2]);

Set<String[]> set = new TreeSet<>(comp);
set.addAll(arrayList);
set.forEach(arr->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Prints

```
[2, car, goodbye]
[1, hello, goodbye]
[3, jack, goodbye]
[4, mcdonalds, goodbye]
```

You can either keep them in the set or add them to an array list.

And if here is a universal solution that lets you choose any set of indices you want to filter.

First create a helper method to build the predicate.  It maintains a set to detect previously seen elements.

```
public static Predicate<String[]> using(int... i) {
    Set<String> seen = ConcurrentHashSet.newKeySet();
    return e -> seen.add(Arrays.stream(i).mapToObj(r -> e[r])
        .collect(Collectors.joining("")));
}
```

Then, simply filter the values calling the method to generate a predicate.

```
arrayList = arrayList.stream().filter(using(1,2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
arrayList.forEach(
        arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Prints

```
[1, hello, goodbye]
[2, car, goodbye]
[3, jack, goodbye]
[4, mcdonalds, goodbye]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create first a class: (it's more readable, but of course you could just use indexes,like ArrayList[0] = index, ArrayList[1]=message1...etc )

```
public class yourClass {
    Integer index;
    String message1;
    String message2;
    yourClass(Integer a, String b, String c){
        index = a;
        message1 = b;
        message2=c;
    }
}
```

then you could simply use for / foreach

```
 class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        ArrayList<yourClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        yourClass a = new yourClass(1,"hello","goodbye");
        yourClass b = new yourClass(2,"hello","goodbye");
        yourClass c = new yourClass(3,"hello","goodbye");
        yourClass d = new yourClass(4,"helloooooooooooo","goodbyeeeeeeeeee");
        yourClass e = new yourClass(5,"helloo","hellooo");
        arrayList.add(a);
        arrayList.add(b);
        arrayList.add(c);
        arrayList.add(d);
        arrayList.add(e);
        arrayList.forEach(el->{
            arrayList.forEach(el2->{
                if((el.message2 == el2.message2) && (el.message1 == el2.message1)){
                    arrayList.remove(el.index);
                }
            });
        });
        System.out.println((arrayList));
    }
}
```

Or if you're good at streams, this is also a good solution, see this:https://www.techiedelight.com/remove-elements-list-satisfies-predicate-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to exclude duplicates from this list using a custom comparator, comparing by the second and third column of the strings array. But there is no guarantee that the order of the elements remain the same. If it matters, you can sort them by the first column, or load them to some other list and check if this list [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) elements from the first list:

```java
List<String[]> list1 = Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{"1", "hello", "goodbye"},
        new String[]{"2", "car", "goodbye"},
        new String[]{"3", "jack", "goodbye"},
        new String[]{"4", "mcdonalds", "goodbye"},
        new String[]{"5", "hello", "goodbye"});

TreeSet<String[]> treeSet =
        new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(arr -> arr[1] + arr[2]));

treeSet.addAll(list1);
```

```java
treeSet.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [2, car, goodbye]
// [1, hello, goodbye]
// [3, jack, goodbye]
// [4, mcdonalds, goodbye]
```

---

1. Sort by the first column:

   ```java
   List<String[]> list2 = treeSet.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(arr -> arr[0]))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
2. Load to another list and check if this list [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) elements from the first list:

   ```java
   List<String[]> listSet = new ArrayList<>(treeSet);

   List<String[]> list2 = list1.stream()
           .filter(listSet::contains)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

---

```java
list2.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [1, hello, goodbye]
// [2, car, goodbye]
// [3, jack, goodbye]
// [4, mcdonalds, goodbye]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to find duplicate elements in array in effective way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344781/14838237)</sup>